# How to retrieve AVRO Schema from Schema Registry from a message in a Topic from java consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We are using Confluent Kafka with schema registry.  We have more than 40 topics.  Our application writes avro messages to these topics, using the schema from the registry.

From what I understand, when using the registry, the message doesn't contain the actual schema but a reference to the schema ( schema id ) from the registry.   I am working on a utility in Java, that will accept a topic name or a list of topic names and retrieve a limited number ( maybe 50 ) of messages, from each of these topics.  This utility should then convert the avro message to a json.

All the examples that I have seen, still have to give the schema for being able to convert the byte[] to json.

I was hoping and wondering, if it is possible to get the schema from the registry dynamically using the information from the avro message ( the schema id ) from the topic and use that to convert the message to json.

Is it possible to do so?  Can someone give me an example on how to achieve that?

Thank you

**Updates**

@eik

*Trial 1*

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
    "io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroDeserializer");
final Consumer<String, GenericRecord> genericConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
genericConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("TOPICNAME"));            
while (true) {
    final ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> genericConsumerRecords = genericConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
    System.out.println("genericConsumerRecords.count() : " + genericConsumerRecords.count() + " genericConsumerRecords.isEmpty() : " + genericConsumerRecords.isEmpty());
    genericConsumerRecords.forEach(genericRecord1 -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("convert(genericRecord1.value()) -> " + convert(genericRecord1.value()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //
    });
}
```

**This is the output** `genericConsumerRecords.count() : 0 genericConsumerRecords.isEmpty() : true`

**Note:** : The convert method is the one in the answer below

*Trial 2*

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
   "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
final Consumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("TOPICNAME"));

while (true) {
    final ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
    System.out.println("consumerRecords.count() : " + consumerRecords.count() + " consumerRecords.isEmpty() : " + consumerRecords.isEmpty());
    consumerRecords.forEach(record1 -> {
       String string = new String(record1.value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s \n", record1.offset(), record1.key(), string);
    });
}
```

**This is the output**

```
consumerRecords.count() : 60 consumerRecords.isEmpty() : false
offset = 0, key = e3bff195-08a7-4c58-99de-98ffe2d460e6, value = He52d6fa6-841f-430c-8bf7-bd4c7b684129 http://schemaregistryurl:8081/subjects/TOPICNAME-value/versions/1/schema Canon Message to represent CustomerPrefAVRFAST 162019-08-07T08:35:35.9950728 QA1-Test-0421-16$CustomerPrefData 1He52d6fa6-841f-430c-8bf7-bd4c7b684129 RawH862437d0-e260-45f9-ab5e-345b536d685a02020-04-21T17:48:52.601Z$CustomerPref POL_MAST02020-04-21T11:17:28.241ZHe3bff195-08a7-4c58-99de-98ffe2d460e69
False&1900-01-01T00:00:00He3bff195-08a7-4c58-99de-98ffe2d460e6He3bff195-08a7-4c58-99de-98ffe2d460e6
```

**Note:** :  I had to remove some non-ascii characters from the output

The second method does give the output, but it is a byte[], need to get the json output.   Have tried different ways unsuccessfully.

How do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 - Is it possible to do what I want to try to do?  Appreciate if you can help with the  above question

Comment: AKHQ can display Confluent Avro messages. Perhaps you can [read the source code](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/blob/master/src/main/java/org/akhq/models/Record.java#L103) for a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroDeserializer` to get a standard Apache Avro `GenericRecord` and then do:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;

class GenericRecord2Json {
  String convert(GenericRecord record) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Schema schema = record.getSchema();
    DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
    Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, outputStream, /* pretty= */ true);
    writer.write(record, encoder);
    encoder.flush();

    return outputStream.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  }
}
```

Which returns your message in JSON format. The Schema is retrieved by `record.getSchema()`.

Comment: Updating the question with what I tried and the output.  It is too long for comment.  It did not work for me - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't forget to [configure the `schema.registry.url`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html#avro-deserializer), since you are using the Confluent Avro format.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I have set the schemregistryurl as well.  Just did not add all the properties set  in the example above.  Anything else I need to check.

Comment: I made some more changes in the code, following the example in the link and now it is working.  Thanks